# Search and Sort returning Default View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, entity-framework

I'm looking to set up a view of my Users data, with paging, sorting and search features following the approach here [Asp.net/MVC Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). The page runs correctly, with Debug data showing the filter and search is being triggered, but I keep getting the default page as a return instead of a filtered or sorted list.

Index

```
         @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <p>
                    Find by Name: @Html.TextBox("searchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
                </p>
            }

        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Email
                </th>
                <th>
                    FirstName
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortPram, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Create Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
            </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<br/>
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",new {page, SortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Controller

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
ViewBag.NameSortPram = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "name_asc";
ViewBag.DateSortPram = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

if (searchString != null)
{
    page = 1;
}
else
{
    searchString = currentFilter;
}

ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

var users = from u in db.Users
    select u;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Searching for " + searchString);
    users =
        users.Where(
            u =>
                u.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||
                u.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
            );
}
switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "name_desc":
        Debug.WriteLine("Changing order " + sortOrder);
        users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastName);
        break;
    case "name_asc":
        Debug.WriteLine("Changing order " + sortOrder);
        users = users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
        break;
    case "Date":
        Debug.WriteLine("Changing order " + sortOrder);
        users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.CreatedDate);
        break;
    default:
        Debug.WriteLine("Changing order " + sortOrder);
        users = users.OrderBy(u => u.UserId);
        break;
}

int pageSize = 3;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

return View(db.Users.OrderBy(u => u.UserId).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

}
```

Comment: Your form only contains a control for `searchString`. When you post, the `sortOrder` and `currentFilter` are always `null`

Comment: Bad cut and paste.  Fixed now.

Comment: You form still only contains one textbox (`@Html.TextBox("searchString" ..)` - nothing relating to the other 2 parameters will be posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can u get the filtered or sorted results if you keep returning a new query with no filtering `b.Users.OrderBy(u => u.UserId)`:

Wrong return:

```
return View(db.Users.OrderBy(u => u.UserId).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

you should `users` object filtered and ordered.

Update 1:
try something like:

```
return View(users.Skip(pageNumber*pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
```

Comment: I figured that's where the problem is, but can't find the correct return to use.

Comment: That worked.  In the end I used Skip(0) since I need to see the first page of results.   `return View(users.Skip(0).Take(pageSize).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));`  Thanks @OldTrain